# UITabBar is removed when pushed back on UITableViewController but not ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have an iPhone app, which has a `UITabBar` with 5 tabs in it, each of the 5 tabs have `NavigationViewcontroller` which push to other "sub" views as the user selects different options.

2 of the tabs are `UItableViews` and 3 are UIviews.

When I push from a `UITableView` to another uiview, then return to the original `UITableView`, the tab bar appears white instead of a is original bar with 5 tbs on it.

However if I do the same thing from one of the 3 `UIView` (which is are the tab bar) to another `UIView`, then return the tab bar is as fine.

I am using **storyboards** (for the second time) and I have checked the Atributes inspector in the navigation controller and the root views for the `UIView` that are working and the table `UITableView` that are not and I cannot see any difference.

My question is should they be the same?

I also use this code to try and stop the bar from being hidden in the `init` method of the first view and the tab view,

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=NO;
}
return self;
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated as my reading has left me blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following way to hide the bottom bar. When pushed it hides the bottom bar and on popping it reveals back the bottom bar

```
- (void)pushNewViewController{
  MyNewViewController *viewController = [self instantiateNewViewController];
  viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I have tried this and It is still sadly not working

Comment: yes for some reason that is not working, I have added the <UINavigationController> to the .h and set self.navigationcontroller.delegate=self; anything else a miss?

Comment: Well, the problem is that you set this property on destination view controller not on the source view controller. I will edit my answer to reflect the changes. You wont need any delegate for this. It is simple enough.

Comment: I made the destination view controller the delegate and it works, thanks time.